# Como diminuir as casas decimais com EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou criando uma aplicação com Node.js, utilizando a view engine EJS, e tenho um cálculo de `preço * quantidade`, porém o resultado fica algo como `80.9999999`. Alguém sabe como posso arredondar isso usando o EJS?

Segue o código:

```
<tbody>
                <% for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <%= i+1 %> </td>
                        <td> <a href="/produto/<%= items[i].produtoId %>"><%= items[i].nome %></a> </td>
                        <td> R$ <%= items[i].preco %></td>
                        <form method="POST">
                            <td> <input type="text" name="quantidade" class="form-control" value="<%= items[i].quantidade %>"> </td>
                            <td>R$ <%= items[i].preco * items[i].quantidade %> </td> 
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="carrinhoId" value="<%= items[i]._id %>">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Salvar" formaction="/carrinho/save">
                                <a class="btn btn-light" href="/verificar-pedido?pedido=<%= items[i]._id %>"> Pedido </a>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Deletar" formaction="/carrinho/delete">
                            </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EJS interpreta expressões em JavaScript. Desse modo, basta você utilizar algum método de arredondamento do objeto global [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).

- Para arredondar, utilize [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round);
- Para arredondar para cima, utilize [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil);
- Para arredondar para baixo, utilize [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

Por exemplo:

```js
<%= Math.round(items[i].preco * items[i].quantidade) %>
```

Um outro exemplo fora do EJS:

```js
console.log(Math.round(4.3)); // 4
console.log(Math.round(4.5)); // 5
console.log(Math.round(4.7)); // 5

console.log(Math.floor(4.5)); // 4
console.log(Math.ceil(4.5)); // 5
```

No entanto, se você desejar **diminuir as casas decimais**, sem arredondar, você poderá utilizar o método `toFixed`, presente na instância de qualquer `Number` no JavaScript. Note que esse método retornará uma `string`, e não `number`.

Por exemplo:

```js
const num = (45.56565656).toFixed(2)

console.log(num); // "45.56"
console.log(typeof num); // "string"
```

Então no EJS você pode utilizar:

```js
<%= (items[i].preco * items[i].quantidade).toFixed(2) %>
//                                         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

Comment: Funcionou cara!muitíssimo obrigado!!!principalmente por ter explicado o funcionamento!